# BeautifulSoup: How to extract data after specific html tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have following html and I am trying to figure out how exactly I can tell BeautifulSoup to extract td after certain html element. In this case I want to get data in `<td>` after `<td>Color Digest</td>`

```
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> 2,36,156,38,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, </td>
</tr>
```

This is the entire HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="clear:both; width:100%;margin:0px; font-size:1pt;">
<br>
<br>
<table>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#AAAAAA">
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> 2,36,156,38,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this all of your HTML? Or is it in a larger file with many other <td>s and <tr>s? And is there guaranteed to be only one "Color Digest" element in the html you're parsing?

Comment: No this is just a snippet of the html, so I want to actually get the mechanism of getting element after a certain element. Like in XPath you can tell I need first td after <td>Color Digest</td>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to iterate over a list of `<td>` and stop once you've found your data.

Example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><tr><td>X</td><td>Color Digest</td><td>THE DIGEST</td></tr></html>')
for cell in soup.html.tr.findAll('td'):
    if 'Color Digest' == cell.text:
         print cell.nextSibling.text
```